# Real Analysis Exercise

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X = \lbrace f \in l^1, \sum_{1}^{\infty} n|f(n)| < \infty\rbrace$. Show that $X$ is a proper dense subspace of $l^1$, hence is not complete.

I figured out that $X$ is a proper set of $l^1$, but I have no idea how to prove it's a dense subspace of $l^1$. Moreover, how does the completeness follow? Thanks.

Comment: Show it's a subspace. Then show it contains a set whose linear span is dense (like the set of standard unit vectors). Complete sets are closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given, let $f \in \ell^1$. We have to show that it is possible to find $g \in X$ such that $\|f - g\|_{\ell^1} < \epsilon$.

$f = \{a_n\} \in \ell^1$, then there is N such that $\sum_{n = N+1}^{\infty}|a_n| < \epsilon$. 
Then let $g = (a_1,\dots,a_N,0,0,\dots)$.

Clearly $g \in X$ and $\|f - g\|_{\ell^1} < \epsilon$.

It is trivially not complete: take $f \in \ell^1 \setminus X$ and find a Cauchy sequence that converges to $f$. (You can construct the sequence by hand using elements of the form of $g$)